# How to check if a sum of one pair of a factor is equal to the difference of another pair?

Tags: python

I have developed a function that finds the factors of any given number and displays them as pairs. I am now wanting to check if there are at least two pairs of factors where the sum of one of the pairs is equal to the difference of another pair. Pairs are the factors of one specific number. For instance, the number 6 would work as 2+3 = 6-1. I'm not sure how to start the code without importing. I've included my code for finding the factor pairs.

Edit: a user below has provided a solution; however, is there a way that I could allow his solution to solve for a larger number of pairs rather than solely 2 pairs? For instance, the number 84 is one of these numbers; however, when its put through his solution, nothing is outputted.

```
def Factors(value):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(value**0.5)+1):
        if value % i == 0:
            factors.append((i, value // i))
    return factors
```

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: 6*2 <> 6.

Comment: I am mainly focused on the two factors that directly achieve 6. 6 and 2 would equate to 12 rather than 6.

Comment: The *inefficient* way would be to have nested loops go through all pairs of factor pairs so you could test your condition on each.  A better way would be to build a dictionary whose keys are numbers and the value at each key is the list of pairs whose pair sums to that value, do the same for differences; I'll let you figure it out from there.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to build off of that!

Comment: @JunirOkoc If you input 84 to my solution (i.e., if `x == 84`) then you get `(3, 28) (4, 21)`, not nothing as you said. Also, `Factors(84) == [(1, 84), (2, 42), (3, 28), (4, 21), (6, 14), (7, 12)]`: which are the other pairs that should be outputted???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = # your number
for p1, p2 in combinations(Factors(x), 2):
    if sum(p1) == abs(p2[0] - p2[1]) or sum(p2) == abs(p1[0] - p1[1]):
        print(p1, p2)
```

This is a solution implementing a great suggestion from @ScottHunter (its complexity is O(n)):

```
x = # this is your number, 6 for example
f = Factors(x)

dct = {}
for p in f:
    s = sum(p)
    if s in dct:
        dct[s].append(p)
    else:
        dct[s] = [p]

for p1 in f:
    d = abs(p1[0] - p1[1])
    if d in dct:
        print(*((p1, p2) for p2 in dct[d]))
```

How does this work? First you build a dictionary which maps a sum of factors to a list of pairs that sum up to that value. For example here `f1 + f2 == f3 + f4 == k`:

```
dct = {k: [(f1, f2), (f3, f4)]}
```

Then you iterate over your pairs of factors, find their difference (with `d = abs(p[0] - p[1])`). Now, **if** their is a pair `(x1, x2)` whose difference `d` is equal to the sum of another pair `(x3, x4)` then for sure `(x3, x4)` can be found in `dct[d]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you just explain how we are able to access the p1 and p2; I am a little stumped on that part also, how could I get it to work with more complex number like 100

Comment: @JunirOkoc I improved the answer with an explanation

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. The code only works for numbers with only two pairs of factors; how could I edit this to work with more pairs?

Comment: @JunirOkoc Could you please tell me an example in which there is a number with more than a pair of factors that have this property?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: 211 has 2 and 841 has 3

Comment: @ScottHunter Then the problem is with the user's function. Indeed, `Factors(211) == [(1, 211)]` and `Factors(841) == [(1, 841), (29, 29)]`. How can I find two pairs of pairs if I only have one pair?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: My bad: values are off by 1.  For example, 210 has pairs (14,15)&(6,35) and (7,30)&(5,42).

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: 840 has 3 pairs.  341880 has 4.

Comment: @ScottHunter If you try to run my code you'll see that it's working with the inputs and outputs that you provided :) I think the OP made some other mistake

Comment: @RiccardoBucco: *I* wasn't commenting on your code, but responding to your question asking for an example of  a number with "more than a pair of factors that have this property".

Answer (score 1):

You can compare each pair with each other. There is a convenient function in the `itertools` module, which is part of the python standard library. Try

```
import itertools as it
for (p1,p2),(q1,q2) in it.permutations(Factors(x),2):
    if p1+p2 == abs(q1-q2):
        print('{} + {} == |{} - {}|'.format(p1,p2,q1,q2)
```

Comment: You do not "have to compare each pair with each other".

Comment: @ScottHunter Why wouldn't I have to? There is a relation, that can be true for any pair of pairs. To get all of them, you have to check all of them. The question does not clearly state, that only one such related pair of factors is looked for. But even then would you have to look at all combinations in the worst case. If I made an error, could you more explicitly point it out or give an algorithm, which does not compare each point witch each other?

Comment: @ScottHunter Well looking at the Solution provided by Riccardo Bucco, you are probably right. I will correct the statement.